# Question about the definition of finite signed measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given$(X,\mathscr{X},\mu)$,we  define a positive measure  finite using $\mu(X)\lt \infty$,
So,from my idea,we can define a finite signed measure $\nu$ as $|\nu(X)| \lt \infty$,but the fact is not as I think,The textbook defines a finite signed measure as $| \nu |(X) =\nu^{+}(X)+\nu^{-}(X) \quad with \quad \nu^{+}(X)\lt \infty \quad and  \quad \nu^{-}(X)\lt \infty $.why does it define signed measure finite using a complicated way.Is my idea about the definition of finite signed measure limitation?

Comment: Both are equivalent definitions.

Comment: My definition is not well defined,as Josh Keneda said.

Comment: You're right, i read again your question and i confused the notation |v|(x) |v(x)| (and in general they are not even the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textbook definition is better because it guarantees that the signed measure is always well-defined.

For example, take $\nu$ to be the usual Lebesgue measure on the positive reals and its negative on the negative reals. You could maybe try arguing that $\nu(\mathbb{R}) = \infty -\infty = 0$, since $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of the null sets $(-n, n)$. So maybe your definition would be satisfied with this setup. But this doesn’t actually give a well-defined measure.

Let $F_n = (-n-1, -n] \cup (2n, 2n + 2]$ for $n = 0, 1, 2…$ (Basically I’m taking one unit of negative weight and two units of positive weight at every step, in such a way that they cover the real line.)

Then $\nu(\mathbb{R}) = \sum \nu(F_n) = \infty$, which contradicts the measure we gave it above.

You can imagine taking $-F_n$ instead of $F_n$, and you’d conclude that the full real line should have $-\infty$ as its measure. In fact, you could rig the sets $F_n$ so that they cover $\mathbb{R}$ and so that the sum of their measures is anything you’d like.

This is similar in spirit to the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem), which explains why we really want absolute convergence instead of conditional convergence for series. Same idea here. If you have a set that contains a subset of infinite positive measure and another subset of infinite negative measure, then there’s not a consistent way to measure the whole set.

Comment: To get a well-defined finite signed measure, you need both the positive and negative parts to be finite. For a general (non-finite) signed measure, it’s okay for *one* of the parts to be infinite, but not both. As soon as you allow both the positive and negative parts to assign infinite measures, you introduce inconsistencies in your measure (because $\infty - \infty$ can’t be given a consistent definition in this context).

Comment: Thank you.You explained it very clearly.

Comment: You’re welcome! :)